# Terminology for non-empty suprema preserving function

Tags: category-theory, terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

Is there an established name for a map of complete lattices $f : L \to L'$ that preserves nonempty suprema? I.e. for all $U \subseteq L$ with $U \neq \emptyset$,
$$ f( \bigvee U) = \bigvee_{u \in U} f(u)$$

An example of such a map is $a \mapsto a \lor c$.

I have heard this property being called 'continuous' but I would like to find a reference.
Another name for preserving the empty suprema is 'strictness', since this means that $f(\bot) = \bot$ (note that $a \mapsto a \lor c$ is not strict).

I'm mainly interested in the case where we have a binary operation $\ast : L \times L \to L$ that preserves non-empty suprema in each argument.

(A structure $(Q, \ast : Q \times Q \to Q)$ where $Q$ is a complete lattice and $\ast$  preserves *all* suprema in each argument is known as a [quantale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantale).)

Thank you!

Comment: Really I think we should call this *co*continuous. Suprema are colimits in the natural perspective of a lattice as a category

Comment: @FShrike in the category theory terminology, 'cocontinuous' would imply preservation of the empty supremum (i.e. initial object), wouldn't it?

Comment: That’s just saying you preserve the empty supremum. But yes, that’s right.